# How to listen for variable to be declared|defined|available

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

How to 'listen' for the event that a variable has been declared/created?

From CSS I know that I can fire upon availibility of a CSS class like this:

```
let logo = document.querySelector('.test');
logo.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('CSS class .test is defined now!');
});
```

Analogously to that I am looking for a 'querySelector' for variables, something like:

```
logo = window.hasOwnProperty('window.myVariable');
logo.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('window.myVariable is defined now!');
});
```

Usage: I want to fire code as soon as an externally async loaded script has established the variable in question.

**EDIT:** some background
In my web page (code I controll) I am loading a 3rd party .js script from another domain (code I don't controll). That script than loads more code from its domain. This 2nd script establishes a variable 'window.something { "key":"value",...} and then issues the loading of a third script. I want to interact with my js code to patch the variable as soon as it is available and before the 3rd script is executed.
@reyno suggested the use of Proxy. My latest approach is to establish the variable myself and then watch for changes using Proxy.

```
<body>
  <script>
    // establish variable 
    window.someVariable={"someKey":"someValue"};
    
    // set up Proxy listener:
    var targetProxy = new Proxy(window.someVariable,{
      set: function (target, key, value) {
        console.log(`${key} set to ${value}`);
        target[key] = value;
        // change occured, thus 3rd party set values
        // ... add more code here ...
        return true;
      }
    });
    
    // test:
    console.log(window.someVariable);
    window.someVariable.someKey="NEW CONTENT";
    console.log(window.someVariable);
  </script>

  <!-- load the external script -->
  <script src="https://"></script>

  <!-- rest of html page ... -->

</body>
```

The problem now is that the other software, running in its own pop up window, looks like having its own scope, an 'own' window.someVariable, not overwriting mine.

Comment: Please may you share a [mcve] of the issue rather than the solution you're trying? Show us why you need this.

Comment: You can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) do determine when a property changes *(only works for objects)*.

Comment: @Reyno Yes, that worked, see my 'edit'. But the problem now changed.

Answer (score 1):

First, set a custom event listener, I like to call it "notify".

```js
document.addEventListener("notify", function() {
   console.log('window.myVariable is defined now!');
})
```

In your script that will load later, trigger this event listener when your variable is created.

```js
const myVariable = "hello world";
document.dispatchEvent(new Event("notify"));
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/NHerwich/8b4gedxy/

Comment: This requires the OP to have access to the loaded script. Why not just ensure the correct loading order?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't think about OP not having access to the script. If he does, my answer should work. What do you mean by correct loading order?

Comment: I am loading a 3rd party script in a HTML. At a uncertain time, that script will be loaded, after DOMContentLoaded and before DocumentLoaded. That script defines a variable 'windows.something'. I want to act upon this var as soon as it is available (patch it).

Comment: @jamacoe If you know it'll be before `DocumentLoaded` why not listen to that instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox that particular 3rd party script will fire another script from its domain, also before DocumentLoaded, and I want to act in between.